# Make smooth texture transition animation in BGE

Tags: animation, materials, game-engine, keyframes

I have a skydome model to use in my game and 2 sky materials for it I want to have it fade between during an animation, like a day-night cycle with a smooth transition between day and night skies.  I have the placements of all of my keyframes ready for the animation, but I need to know what property(s) of my materials I need to change to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can fade between two materials, but you could easily set up a mix shader within a single material and animate the factor with keyframes.  So the single material would contain shader setups for your day sky and your night sky, and the mix shader would switch between the two.  It is possible to mix between background shaders FYI (although since you say you have a "skydome" perhaps you are talking about mesh materials, not background materials . . . it's the same principle either way).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input but if I wasn't clear before I need this to work in the BGE.  Updated post.